# indices for surface of revolution

Tags: opengl, vertex

I'd like to implement a surface of revolution.

I already implemented creating Vertices based on a 2D line.
I now want to get the indices to render the mesh with `GL_TRIANGLES`

Here's the code to create the 3D Vertices out of a 2D line:

```
void createVertices(vector<Vector2>& points,unsigned int iterations)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    unsigned int index;

    vector<Vertex> newVertices;
    vector<unsigned int> newIndices;
    for(j = 0; j < points.size();++j)
    {
        for(i =0; i < iterations;++i)
        {
            Vector2 p = points.at(j);
            float theta = M_PI*2.0*(float)i/(float)iterations;
            float x = sinf(theta)*p.x;
            float z = cosf(theta)*p.x;
            newVertices.push_back(Vertex(x,p.y,z));
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the code that will be called to save the Vertices:

```
void addVertices(vector<Vertex>& vertices,vector<unsigned int>& indices)
{
    this->vertices = vertices;
    this->indices = indices;

    unsigned int verticesSize = vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex);
    unsigned int indicesSize = indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int);

    float* vertexBuffer = new float[vertices.size()*sizeof(Vertex)];

    createBuffers(vertices,vertexBuffer);

    glGenVertexArrays(1,&VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glGenBuffers(1,&verticesVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,verticesVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,verticesSize,vertexBuffer,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1,&indicesVBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,indicesVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,indicesSize,&indices[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    delete[] vertexBuffer;
}
```

someone has a basic idea?